# App update is available on Google Play store but there in only open option available instead on Update . How to resolve this issue?

Tags: android

My App is live on Play store and I have enabled force update on App open, but when user is redirected to Google Play store there is only Open option instead of Update option.

Answer (score 1):

If your user install app from anywhere except GooglePlay, when he open googlePlay just can see open and unistall option. So your user must first time install app from googlePlay to get update option when needed or you implement force update in your app and when you publish new version at googlePlay, just download published apk from googlePlay and put it into your force update link. So, even if your user dont install app from googlePlay, with force update he forced to install googlePlay  version.

Please check version of your apk at googlePlay app page. Because sometime it takes 24 hours to publish new version at googlePlay.

Comment: Older version is already downloaded from GooglePlay. I show Update is available alert when there is new update available , that is working fine . But update on Google Play in not shown .

Comment: I see this problem when one of our users download our app from anywhere except googleplay. I believe your user dont install app from GooglePlay.

Comment: If my answer solve your problem please choose my answer as accept answer.

Comment: My users download from Google Play store only they dont have any other source to download the application.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for some time(maybe a couple of hours) before enabling force update in your app as it takes time to reflect update on play store. Also, sometimes google play store app shows cached data so the user may see open app option instead of an update option.

Comment: Version number is shown latest on the play store but the update button is not shown.